# Passing json object to webmethod via jquery ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, webmethod

I am trying to pass a json object to my .net webmethod. 
Here is my C#:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Guncelle(string personel)
{
 return "It came.";
}
```

And my jquery ajax:

```
var saveData = {};
saveData.Isim = isim;
saveData.Soyad = soyisim;
saveData.Firma = firma;
.
.
.
var result = JSON.stringify({ personel: saveData });

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Personeller.aspx/Guncelle",
        data: result,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
           alert(msg.d);
        },
        error: function (msg) {
           alert(msg.d);
        }
})
```

When I run code, it returns 'undefined' with alert. What is the correct way of passing json object to C# Webmethod ? I tried other examples for passing an object but none of them worked for me.

Comment: try {
 "personel": "saveData"
}

Comment: Just pass the `string`, you're trying to pass an object with a property of `personel`.

Comment: Are you expecting a string back or a json object back? if it's a string, then msg.d is rightfully undefined. otherwise, you need to specify the response format as being json.

Answer (score 0):

try this: data: "{personel:'" + saveData+ "'}"